# git branches rebase to dev branch

Tags: git

I created 3 branches using [git graph](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mhutchie.git-graph) in VS Code.

The second and third branches got the code from the first branch which I didn't expect.

I thought each branch will get branched from my development branch. How can I rebase the last two branches to development branch ignoring the code I have in my first branch?
So each branch will not be related to each other.

I tried to stash it but I don't think thats the right way to go.

[image: branches]

Comment: The branch you create will be based on the active branch when the branch is created. To change which commit (and possibly branch) a branch is based on, use `git rebase`

Comment: Have you committed anything on those 2 branches? Because if you **haven't**, you can simply reset them: `git reset --hard the-branch-i-want-to-be-based-on` after having checked out each one of them. No idea how you can achieve that in VS.

Answer (score 1):

**DISCLAIMER**: `git rebase` rewrites history, make sure you have read and understood its manpage before executing the following commands. Having backups certainly helps in case you mess up.

---

So you want to create 3 branches and each branch should contain only a single commit? In that case, use rebase with the `--onto target base branch` syntax:

```
git rebase --onto development branch1^ branch1
git rebase --onto development branch2^ branch2
git rebase --onto development branch3^ branch3
```

`branch1^` means "one commit before the current head of branch1.

---

With Git there are many ways, so another option would be:

```
head=$(git rev-parse branch1)
git checkout -B branch1 development
git cherry-pick "${head}"
# repeat for all 3 branches
```